# How can I make screen comfortable for all mobiles?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I developed a screen on my android mobile then its looks perfect...but when I run screen on another android mobile then its not looks perfect...what is the solution of this problem

Comment: Clipping excess and flowing layouts to hide excess. There are many different *aspect ratios*, which simple scaling cannot account for. The basic issue and solution of aspect ratio differences can be found here https://www.rtings.com/tv/learn/what-is-the-aspect-ratio-4-3-16-9-21-9 (same applies to different mobile devices)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use absolute positioning and absolute sizing, you need to make your app flexible. The main problem that new flutter users face is their content gets overflowed. Most of the times to fix this issue you must wrap your widgets with some sort of scroll, such as `SingleChildScrollView`.

Check this [link](https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/troubleshooting/widget-overflowed-by-pixels/2020/461/) for more details regarding overflowing and this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive) for more details on adaptive apps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Mohammed said, also endeavor to declare your media query heights, widths and work with it at every point you need absolute values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use MediaQuery to make your app responsive and fit well in any screen. [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html), you can find some info about it and a nice video that explains how it works.

Answer (score 0):

use flutter_screenutil plugin , for adapting screen and font size ,
this is the link

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Mohammed said, I'll recommend using "Device preview" during development to see how your app is faring across multiple screen sizes and platforms, and I'll also not recommend fix positioning and sizing instead go for flexible positioning, this is here your use of minAxisSize, maxAxisSize, crossAxisAlignment.stretch and so on will be more useful.